# Удалить из строки первый и последний символ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Насколько знаю, то строки неизменны, соответственно буду использовать метод .replace()

```
a = 'hello'
def remove_char(s):
    s = a.replace(a[-1] + a[0], '')
    return s
print(remove_char(a))
```

***Но функция возвращает 'hello' без изменения.
Я так понимаю нельзя использовать метод .replace с двумя аргументами?***

Comment: `'hello'[1:-1]`     # 'ell'

Comment: @S.Nick а если мне нужна конкретная функция, которая будет удалять первый и последний символ, не зависимо, какой длинны строка будет ?

Comment: @VyacheslavBondarev, его ответ так и делает. Это называется срез.

Comment: "Я так понимаю нельзя использовать метод .replace с двумя аргументами?" - а что, документацию на replace прочитать религия не позволяет? или вы каждый метод будете методом проб и ошибок изучать?

Comment: Уважаемый автор, если мой ответ был полезен, отметьте, пожалуйста, его, как решение.

Comment: @V-Mor уже отметил)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вашу функцию можно реализовать вот так:

```
string = 'hello'

def remove_char(s):
    result = s[1 : -1]
    return result

print(remove_char(string))
```

В консоль будет выведено `ell`. Синтаксис `s[1 : -1]` означает, так называемый, "срез" – получение отрезка строки (хотя, в общем случае не строки, а любой коллекции, к элементам которой можно получить доступ через `[]`), в данном случае, от первого с начала до первого с конца элемента (при том, что нумерация начинается с нулевого).

Подробнее о срезах можно прочитать [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
s = a.replace(a[-1] + a[0], '')
```

В данной строчке вы пытаетесь удалить из строки идущие подряд два символа, равные последнему и первому элементу.

То есть для строки `hello` ваш код будет пытаться удалить из неё `oh`. А так как внутри `hello` нет ни одного `oh`, то вообще никаких изменений произведено не будет.

Если вы, например, вызовете вашу функцию для строки `hooho`, то замена произойдёт, но заменится не то, что вы хотите, а `oh` из середины строки, и на выходе получится `hoo`, вместо ожидаемого `ooh`.

В общем, `replace` удаляет подстроки по значению. А если вам нужно удалять части строки, зная их положение в исходной строке, то используйте срез - правильный пример вам уже привели.